# "hibernate.cfg.xml" properties not loading in dependency Configuration.java properties. | io.hypersistence , hypersistence-utils-hibernate-52 , v3.5.0

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, configuration

**OBSERVATION**

Hi, I'm using 'hypersistence-utils-hibernate-52' of 'io.hypersistence' with version '3.5.0'

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRWDb.png)

Note: Though I've tried 'hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55' as well with same version and also 3.5.1 on both as well.

And tried configuring hibernate by code like this:

```
val cfg = Configuration()
cfg.configure("db/hibernate.cfg.xml")
factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory()
```

The thing is I notice that my 'hibernate.cfg.xml' properties are loaded while in implementing that function 'buildSessionFactory()' and I can observe them alright under 'serviceRegistry' component till 'HibernateTypesContributer' ( To be noted they are like 79 properties there )

[HibernateTypesContributer.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKuE6.png)

But the thing is form here on out, through 'contributeType()' function call.... successive function calls takes program control till first initialization of Configuration.java (inherited by Serializer), which in turn has this load() function meant to load further properties from any properties files (files already specified)

[stackTrace from HibernateTypesContributer to Configuration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yulqh.png)

And there we see that Configuration.java already has 53 properties (which it got by Environment.getProperties() on init)

[Configuration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAE9j.png)

load() function is about loading properties from one custom file and already 3 predefined properties file ( including hibernate.properties file )

[Configuration.java load() predefined properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we1iJ.png)

Application.properties file had some properties which are added into Configuration.java to make its properties total be 64

[After initialization of Configuration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxX6m.png)

And these are the only properties loaded into it upon its initialzation.

PS: I'm certain the hibernate.cfg.xml properties loaded in beginning and confirmed, even the size can be seen to be 79 whereas in Configuration.java, 64 properties were in total ( and it definitely did not have the property I was expecting that was in the config.xml file)

> **BACKGROUND**
> I was expecting it to also load properties of hibernate.cfg.xml, especially needed for my case scenario where I put 'objectMapperSupplier' property in my already available hibernate.cfg.xml and it ought JsonConfiguration would need Configuration to check if that property exists to create WrapperObjectMapper capable of returning objectMapperSupplier.
>
> Though there was one instance I was able to get that in the beginning when I was working with problem related to ObjectMapper, (That would mean it really was loading hibernate.cfg.xml properties) but till now, i've not observed that.
>
> Posting here because I'm unable to understand the current code being able to even pass those hibernate.cfg.xml properties. So even if I might've messed up somehow, I'd atleast now like to understand the code.

**CONCLUSION**
With currently how it seems, I think the dependency has the bug.

**EXPECTATION LOGICALLY**
Either the following of the two things should happen:-

1. Configuration.java which has load() function and loads further properties from predefined property files. ( PS: It ought to also have some path or code to load properties from 'hibernate.cfg.xml' )
2. HibernateTypesContributer.java 'contributeType()' functions should send 'hibernate.cfg.xml' properties ahead along. (so Configuration.java is initialized with those)

Comment: Here's the relevant 'Question' I posted on github where this concern continued.

https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/648